# How do I make MonoDevelop recognize nameof syntax from C# 6.0?

Tags: c#, monodevelop, c#-6.0, nameof

I'm in MonoDevelop v5.9.6. Although it seems to support C# 6.0, the editor doesn't recognize the `nameof` keyword, and it marks it red, because it tries to recognize it as if it were an identifier.

> [image: nameof appears red]

Is there any hack I can use to make it work in the editor, without breaking the compilation somehow?

Comment: Why do you stick on such an old version? 7.x has been out for a long while https://blog.lextudio.com/status-of-monodevelop-xamarin-studio-253da80d022c

Comment: Thats the version that comes with Unity. If I were going to change now, I would probably try to switch to VS, or preferably, VSCode.

Comment: https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/01/05/discontinuing-support-for-monodevelop-unity-starting-in-unity-2018-1/ Unity has switched officially. JetBrain Rider is also an option.

Comment: Yea, I noticed they dropped MonoDevelop in 2018.1. Thanks for the tip, I didn't know Rider yet. If it's anything like Android Studio, it's probably a good IDE. But I'm trying to avoid the "overhead" of changing my programming environment for this particular project until I finish it...

Answer (score 1):

This hack works:

```
// hack to make MonoDevelop recognize nameof syntax from C#6.0
using nameof = System.Func<string>;
```

The editor recognizes it as "returning a string" and doesn't give any errors when used with an argument, like, for instance `nameof(object.Equals)`.

> [image: syntax is recognixed]

When I <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Space</kbd> to show the signature of the call, VSCode ignores it, and MonoDevelop shows this:

> [image: CTRL+SHIFT+SPACE shows Invoke]

VSCode (which supports the nameof syntax) doesn't complain about it either. The lexer recognizes the `nameof` as a keyword (in red) but identifies it as a delegate when I hover.
In any case I don't get any errors.

> [image: VSCode recognizes it too]

What is even more intriguing, the compilers (both Mono and VS) simply ignore the `using` instruction and also accept usages of `nameof`, which works normally.

Now, the [followup question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51457554/9638388) would be... why though? Why won't the compilers complain about it?

Comment: If true, that would be a bug in MonoDevelop's semantic analysis.... `nameof(object.Equals)` wouldn't be legal if `nameof` were a type alias or a real type... you'd need `new nameof(...)`.  Also, the argument count doesn't match.  Are you sure this hack makes it "recognize the syntax" as opposed to just changing the color?

Comment: @Ben When I do `var x = nameof(object.Equals);` and hover the mouse on `var`, it shows it interpreted x as String; When I hover on `nameof`, it shows `public delegate string Func<string>()`. So it works, even though the argument count doesn't match. It also accepts anything in there, even a type.

Comment: Does that behavior change with/without the `using`?  Does it change if the identifier is changed from `nameof` to something else?  It sounds like the semantic analyzer does know about `nameof`, and the `using` doesn't have any effect.

Comment: @Ben I updated it with more screenshots. The blue color in `nameof` shows it's recognizing it as a type (the delegate from the using) and it seems it's assuming it is a constructor call, even though I didn't write `new`. However, when I CTRL+SHIFT+SPACE inside the argument, it shows `Invoke`. If I change it to `using somethingElse` and call `somethingElse` the same happens.