# Why doesn't the compiler give any errors or warnings when using this hack?

Tags: c#, syntax, c#-6.0, nameof

In my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51457497/9638388), I found a hack to make this syntax work in MonoDevelop editor:

```
// hack to make MonoDevelop recognize nameof syntax from C#6.0
using nameof = System.Func<string>;
```

The C# compilers (Mono and VS) don't give any warnings or errors, and usages of the `nameof` keyword also work normally. My question is why.

Comment: That code is valid C# 5 code and it should remain valid after updating C# compiler version.

Comment: Hm.. that makes sense. Because if `nameof` wasn't a keyword before, then when they introduced it, it couldn't be a "reserved word" everywhere, right? But how does that work? For example if I put `using int` it doesn't work. What's the difference for the lexer/parser?

Comment: My wild guess: The compiler folks thought of your hack (well more likely, your class of hack), and put in code (and a test case) to handle it.  When a change is made to the language, great care us taken to avoid it being a "breaking change".  Do you get a warning ("hmm, did you really mean this" or something) if you compile it with a compiler that handles name of?

Comment: @Flydog57 not at all, no warnings, no errors.

Comment: I think if `nameof(test)` is expanded early enough to `"test"` in the compilation (like C++ template expansion), then when C# compiler processes the `using nameof` part, it remains a valid using statement but nothing else uses it. As a result, neither error nor warning should be given. (You might check Roslyn source code for more details.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm **not** a language lawyer but I believe the reason your code works is that `nameof` is a [contextual keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/#contextual-keywords)

Let's take a step back to a more general case.  If you try to create a [`using alias directive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive) for the keyword `if` you get an error...

```
using if = System.Func<string>;  // "CS1001: Identifier expected" error
```

… unless you prefix the name with `@` ...

```
using @if = System.Func<string>;  // No "CS1001: Identifier expected" error
```

Similarly you get a CS1003 error if you try to declare a variable of the aliased type ...

```
if foo = () => "Hello, World";  // "CS1003: Syntax error, '(' expected" error
```

… unless you prefix the name with an `@` sign …

```
@if foo = () => "Hello, World";  // No "CS1003: Syntax error, '(' expected" error
```

Contextual keywords on the other hand do **not** need to be prefixed by `@` …

```
using nameof = System.Func<string>;

nameof bar = () => "Hello, World!";

Console.WriteLine(nameof(nameof));
```

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if contextual keywords like these can by handled by a lexer or have to be handled by a parser.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm also not a compiler builder ;-)  If you really want to know, the answer for at least one compiler might be discovered by examining the Roslyn sources: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn